# Linked list head address changes C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure, scanf

I created linked list of my structure, but for some reason every time I add another link it changes head address, but I want y head address be first entry. this is my code:

```
struct checkPoints *tgh = NULL;
struct checkPoints **linkedlist = &tgh;
struct checkPoints *cp = malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));
chPo = fopen(fileName, mode);
if (chPo == NULL) {
    printf("Can't find the files.");
    exit(1);
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {

        fscanf(chPo, "%c %d %d %d:%d\n", &cp->dropOut, &cp->currentPoint, &cp->competitor, &cp->hour, &cp->minute);
        cp->next = NULL;
        if (*linkedlist == NULL) {
            printf("ONCE");
            *linkedlist = cp;
        } else {
            struct checkPoints *new = *linkedlist;
            while (new->next != NULL) {
                new = new->next;
            }
            new->next = cp;
        }
    }
}
```

every fscanf occurs it changes head address to next, any ideas?

Head address changes after this line: `fscanf(chPo, "%c %d %d %d:%d\n", &cp->dropOut, &cp->currentPoint, &cp->competitor, &cp->hour, &cp->minute);`

The structure is this:

```
struct checkPoints{
char dropOut;
int currentPoint;
int competitor;
int hour;
int minute;
struct checkPoints *next;
};
```

Comment: Use a debugger, step through line by line, check variables at every step.

Comment: I did .. and all it told me that when `fscanf(chPo, "%c %d %d %d:%d\n", &cp->dropOut, &cp->currentPoint, &cp->competitor, &cp->hour, &cp->minute);` occurs head address changes

Comment: well that tells you you should check out the fscanf in detail.. sounds like it's overwriting memory somewhere, hard to tell without seeing dropout etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you do not allocate new nodes, you only have one node that you change over and over again. You need to allocate the node inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any malloc/calloc to create new nodes, which will get added to the list.

You need to **create** new nodes, which will get added to the list. Correct position would be just before

```
    cp->next = NULL;
```

line

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate a fresh `struct checkPoints` for each line you read. It will give you a loop like:

```
struct checkPoints *linkedlist = NULL;
/* … */
for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    struct checkPoints *cp = malloc(sizeof(struct checkPoints));
    fscanf(chPo, "%c %d %d %d:%d\n", &cp->dropOut, &cp->currentPoint, &cp->competitor, &cp->hour, &cp->minute);
    cp->next = NULL;
    if (linkedlist == NULL) {
        linkedlist = cp;
    } else {
        struct checkPoints *new = linkedlist;
        while (new->next != NULL) {
            new = new->next;
        }
        new->next = cp;
    }
}
```

Note that this way of proceeding is highly inefficient as it requires scanning your entire list again for each line. You should either keep a pointer to the tail of your list so that you can append without the `while` loop. A clever alternative is to prepend each line to the front of the list and once you have read the whole file reverse the whole list.

```
struct checkPoints *cp;
for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    cp = malloc(sizeof(struct checkPoints));
    fscanf(chPo, "%c %d %d %d:%d\n", &cp->dropOut, &cp->currentPoint, &cp->competitor, &cp->hour, &cp->minute);
    cp->next = linkedlist;
    linkedlist = cp;
}
cp = linkedlist;
linkedlist = NULL;
struct checkPoints *next = cp;
while (cp) {
    next = cp->next;
    cp->next = linkedlist;
    cp = next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are allocating a single node and over writting the data in the same address.

You need to allocate the memory for new nodes inside the loop.

The following line has to be added in the begining of the loop,

struct checkPoints *cp = malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));