# Infinite while loop in linked list C

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, structure

I ran into a problem, I want to add item to the end of the linked list, but it seems that i am getting sucked in an infinite loop here.

```
void addCheckPoint(struct checkPoints **checkPoint) {
    struct checkPoints *checkPt = *checkPoint;

    while (checkPt->next != NULL) {
        checkPt->next;
        if (checkPt->next == NULL) {
            scanf("%c %d %d %d %d", &checkPt->dropOut, &checkPt->currentPoint, &checkPt->competitor, &checkPt->hour, &checkPt->minute);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would `checkPt->next` ever change ?

Comment: Move the checkpt to point next node.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875395/linked-list-head-address-changes-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void addCheckPoint(struct checkPoints **checkPoint) {
    struct checkPoints *checkPt = *checkPoint;

    while (checkPt != NULL) {
        if (checkPt->next == NULL) {
            scanf("%c %d %d %d %d", checkPt->dropOut, checkPt->currentPoint, checkPt->competitor, checkPt->hour, checkPt->minute);
        }
        checkPt = checkPt->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You never update the value of `checkPt` in your loop.  Change the line

```
checkPt->next;
```

to

```
checkPt = checkPt->next;
```

to fix this.

Note that there may be further problems with the function.  Despite its name, it doesn't actually add anything to the list.  It edits the contents of the tail item instead.  If this isn't deliberate, you'll need to malloc a new element then add it to the tail.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 void addCheckPoint(struct checkPoints **checkPoint) {
        struct checkPoints *checkPt = *checkPoint;

        while (checkPt->next != NULL) {
             checkPt=checkPt->next;
            if (checkPt == NULL) {
                scanf("%c %d %d %d %d", &checkPt->dropOut, &checkPt->currentPoint, &checkPt->competitor, &checkPt->hour, &checkPt->minute);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Suppose there are 0 nodes in the linked list, so `*checkPoint` will be NULL in that case..and `(*checkPoint)->next` will cause error.

Comment: he might be sending a root node.. i don no his aim der

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct checkPoints
{
    char dropOut;
    int currentPoint;
    int competitor;
    int hour;
    int minute;

  struct checkPoints *next;
};

void addCheckPoint(struct checkPoints **checkPoint) {
    while (*checkPoint)
        checkPoint = &(*checkPoint)->next;

    /* FIXME: check malloc() return value */
    *checkPoint = malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));
    (*checkPoint)->next = 0;

    /* NOTE: the leading space in front of the %c */
    scanf(" %c %d %d %d %d",
          &(*checkPoint)->dropOut,
          &(*checkPoint)->currentPoint,
          &(*checkPoint)->competitor,
          &(*checkPoint)->hour,
          &(*checkPoint)->minute);
}

struct checkPoints *list = 0;

int
main ()
{
    addCheckPoint (&list);
    addCheckPoint (&list);
}
```